# Is there an equivalent of git-walk next / git-walk prev in hg?

Tags: git, version-control, mercurial, tortoisehg, changeset

I read that git-walk next / git-walk prev will allow you to move through changesets committed linearly [so that you can play them back in a presentational setting](http://cjohansen.no/en/emacs/live_coding_help_from_git_and_emacs) within your local working copy.

Does hg have any equivalent commands?

(And of course I don't mean the typical -r arguments selecting revisions, I mean moving through changesets in a prev, next fashion)

Comment: could you describe more precisely what that does? (especially the "move through" part. Because I don't get why update with revsets wouldn't work.

Comment: tonfa: I also don't get it -- revsets makes this easy :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [Mq extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MqExtension) for this. That way you can fine-tune each step as you like by refining the MQ patches and finally use `hg qpush` and `hg qpop` to walk through them.

You can also use [revision sets](http://selenic.com/hg/help/revsets) as hinted by Benoit (tonfa). With those,

```
hg update -r 'parents(.)'
```

will walk backwards in the history and

```
hg update -r 'children(.)'
```

will walk forwards. In each case, the parent/child with the highest revision number is used, but that should not concern you with a linear history.